Error when creating a conda-build recipe for a binary file
I am trying to create a conda-build recipe for a package that is distributed as a binary (linux only). I.e. the recipe should simply download the binary and copy it into the appropriate directory.
When I download the binary manually and run it on my computer, it works fine. However, when I build it and run it from the recipe, I get a SIGSEGV error
my meta.yml file:
{% set name = "my_package" %}
{% set version = "1.0.0" %}

package:
  name: {{ name }}
  version: {{ version }}

source:
  - url: https://url_/to_/my_/binary.tar
    sha256: ....


build:
  number: 0

requirements:
  build:
    - gcc
  host:
    - gcc
  run:
    - gcc


about:
  ... more info....

and my build.sh file:
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p $PREFIX/bin

cp my_binary $PREFIX/bin/

chmod +x $PREFIX/bin/my_binary

Then, to install this locally I run:
conda-build path/to/recipe
conda install --offline $HOME/.conda/miniconda3/env/path/to/my_package.tar # created by conda-build

However, the binary installed by conda doesn't run (terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)). The same binary works perfectly when I download it manually from the URL. Why does it break when downloaded and installed by conda? Does conda do anything to the binary? Is it a dependency issue?
Any ideas what could be going on here?
